# Interactive user form in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access-2007

I'd like to design user form where there will be 2 buttons (Query1 and Query2), the text box (InputName) and label (Output).

When user presses the button, then the linked SQL-query will run with the specific parameter (InputName). The output will be displayed in label (Output).

1) How can I parameterized the SQL query? 
2) How can I link the event "button Query 1 is pressed" to SQL query with the paramerter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this. You could place the following VBA in the code module that belongs to the form, assuming that you are interested in only a single field from a single record that you can use as the label Output:

```vb
Private Sub Query1_Click()
    Dim varResult as Variant
    varResult = DLookup("FieldYouAreInterestedIn", "TableName", _
        "Name = '" & InputName & "'")
    If Not IsNull(varResult) Then
        Output.Caption = varResult
    End If
End Sub
```

To open the code module in the Visual Basic Editor, open the form in design view, then choose "View Code" on the Design tab of the ribbon (far right on the screen).

As far as I know, this approach (using `DLookup()`) is not vulnerable for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but you need to research this yourself.

The question was posted some seven weeks ago, so maybe you figured it all out yourself already.